# Showing the data in the correct format within the view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

A user can fill out a form, which is based on multiple questions and each question has 6 fields associated with it.

**The form info is stored in the DB like:**

```
id / audit_id / question_id / score
1003    33          97      3
1004    33          97      0   
1005    33          97      2   
1006    33          97      0   
1007    33          97      2   
1008    33          97      0   
1009    33          98      3   
1010    33          98      1   
1011    33          98      3   
1012    33          98      1   
1013    33          98      3   
1014    33          98      0
```

So in the above example, audit 33 has question_id 97 and 98 which have 6 answers each.

**Controller function to get the information:**

```
Audit::where('audit_id', $auditScore->id)
    ->with('rquestion')
    ->with('rquestion.auditQuestion')
    ->get();
```

Which returns each of the questions in an array:

```
Collection {#486 ▼
  #items: array:78 [▼
    0 => Audit {#490 ▶}
    1 => Audit {#491 ▶}
    2 => Audit {#492 ▶}
    3 => Audit {#493 ▶}
    4 => Audit {#494 ▶}
    5 => Audit {#495 ▶}
    6 => Audit {#496 ▶}
    7 => Audit {#497 ▶}
    8 => Audit {#498 ▶}
    9 => Audit {#499 ▶}
```

The problem I'm facing is that I want to loop through the data, to show the user the following:

> One question and its 6 answers, then the next question and its 6
>   answers

But because each 'question row' is individually returned, I have a question and the score. So for every score I show, it has the question!

Each question will always have 6 answers, so my thoughts were to somehow print the question with the first score, and then the remaining 5 scores on their own?

I'm unsure though how to achieve this. How can I get all 6 scores per `question_id`? Perhaps, each `question_id` contains an array of the 6 scores?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply group them by `question_id`.
Assuming that `$auditList` contains the list of your audits:

```
$groupedQuestions = [];
foreach ($auditList as $singleAudit)
{
    $groupedQuestions[$singleAudit->question_id][] = $singleAudit;
}
```

Than,  you'll have an array like this

```
array:2 [▼
  97 => array:3 [▼
    0 => Audit {#160 ▶}
    1 => Audit {#159 ▶}
    2 => Audit {#163 ▶}
  ]
  98 => array:1 [▼
    0 => Audit {#164 ▶}
    ...
  ]
  ...
]
```

If you want, you can change the code slightly and move the question text in the "upper" array, so it will be easier to fetch it via blade

```
    foreach ($auditList as $singleAudit)
    {
        $groupedQuestions[$singleAudit->question_id]['question'] = $singleAudit->getQuestionText(); // assuming that you have a similar method on your entities
        $groupedQuestions[$singleAudit->question_id]['answers'][] = $singleAudit;
    }
```

Your result array will be similar to this

```
array:2 [▼
  97 => array:2 [▼
    "question" => "This is the question text"
    "answers" => array:3 [▼
      0 => Audit {#160 ▶}
      1 => Audit {#159 ▶}
      2 => Audit {#163 ▶}
    ]
  ]
  98 => array:2 [▼
    "question" => "This is the question text"
    "answers" => array:1 [▼
      0 => Audit {#164 ▶}
    ]
  ]
]
```

and fetching via blade will be like this

```
@foreach($questions as $question)
The question is: {{$question['question']}}    <br />
Answers are: <br />
    @foreach($question['answers'] as $answer)
        {{$answer->id}} <br />
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

printing

> The question is: This is the question text
>   Answers are:
>   1033
>   1034
>   1035
>   ...
>   The question is: This is the question text
>   Answers are:
>   1035
>   ...

Comment: A huge help! and so thoroughly explained. I managed to get the question name through using the relationships associated with the model. Thank you LombaX!